# Offline WordPress post editor/creator

Tags: gratis, text-editor, wordpress, offline

I have a WordPress site hosted on my personal server. I will be unavailable by Internet for a little while, and I'd like to write up some posts for my blog.

Normally, you need to be connected to WordPress to *start* writing the blog, and it will do offline-saving automatically. But this is limited to one entry, per tab. I could use Notepad, but it doesn't have spell check built in. I could use Microsoft Word, but the "Paste from Word" leaves a lot to be desired.

What I'm looking for is a program that does the following:

- Start a new post while offline
- Lets me edit posts I created already with the program
- Spell check
- Uploads new posts when I reconnect
- Has the same features as the online editor (i.e. toolbars, WYSIWYG and code editor)
- Free (as in beer)
- Works on either Windows or Mac OSX

Bonus features:

- Edit posts currently on the website (with an offline copy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I recall the SU blog runs on wordpress, and I was using [windows live writer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Writer) to post on it. Its part of windows essentials, works with WP blogs and if I recall correctly did/does most of what you have listed there

- Start a new post while offline - yes
- Lets me edit posts I created already with the program yes (though I can't remember if it edits uploaded posts)
- Spell check - and grammar check
- Uploads new posts when I reconnect - yes
- Has the same features as the online editor (i.e. toolbars, WYSIWYG and Code editor)kind of - it has its own UI but its broadly compatible and in some ways better
- Free (as in beer) yes
- Works on either Windows or Mac OSX - windows only

Answer (score 3):

StackEdit is a very nice Markdown web app editor that works off-line. I can publish as HTML, but adding a WordPress plugin to work with Markdown is an option.

- *Start a new post while offline*
  As it works offline, you can create any number of documents and update/upload when online
- *Lets me edit posts I created already with the program*
  You'll copy the post content in a new SE document and publish it against the same post ID
- *Spell check*
  IMHO, that's browser territory
- *Uploads new posts when I reconnect*
  After reconnecting, just hit the publish button and it goes live
- *Has the same features as the online editor (i.e. toolbars, WYSIWYG and code editor)*
  Just basic features for the editor
- *Free (as in beer)*
  Yes.
- *Works on either Windows or Mac OSX*
  Yes.
- *Edit posts currently on the website (with an offline copy)*
  See *Upload when reconnected*

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> ### [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io/)
>
> StackEdit is a full-featured, open-source Markdown editor based on PageDown, the Markdown library used by Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites.
>   https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/
>
> Features:
>
> - Real-time HTML preview with Scroll Link feature to bind editor and preview scrollbars
> - Markdown Extra/GitHub Flavored Markdown support and Prettify/Highlight.js syntax highlighting
> - LaTeX mathematical expressions using MathJax
> - WYSIWYG control buttons
> - Online synchronization using Google Drive (multi-accounts) and Dropbox
> - **One click publish on** Blogger, Dropbox, Gist, GitHub, Google Drive, SSH server, Tumblr, **WordPress**

[image: publish on wordpress]

Answer (score 0):

For the mac users there's [blogo](http://www.getblogo.com/). By the time of this writing, the version 1 has been discontinued and the version 2 hasn't yet been released, but there's a video on the official site showing its capabilities. Those include:

- WordPress, tumblr and blogger / blogspot support
- Offline composing
- Editing of already published posts
- Visual editor that uses the actual site theme to render the preview

Possible drawbacks:

- Works only on mac
- Not free

Looks like it doesn't offer spell-checking natively, but there will be a [plugin system](https://getblogo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200793093-What-Power-Ups-means-) and it's possible that there'll be a speelcheck plugin for blogo:

> Power Ups are add-ons that will be available via in-app purchase to make your Blogo experience even better.

Comment: Download link: http://www.getblogo.com/releases/Blogo.dmg?utm_source=Website&utm_medium=Typeform&utm_campaign=Beta%20Publico